# Working in both LAN port

Tags: networking

I have to connect Local LAN in wired network and Internet in WiFi is it possible

Comment: Or this too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/639100/how-to-get-connection-to-both-wifi-as-well-as-lan-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts