# SSH stop working when connecting ethernet cable

Tags: 16.04, ssh, dnsmasq

I greatly appreciate your help to show me what is going on with my network.

The situation is like this: I have a LiDAR sensor that streams UDP data over ethernet cable. The LiDAR has a DHCP server running on its board. I need to install `dnsmasq` so that the LiDAR can directly connect to a NUC (I just followed the manual). Everything works fine. Now I need to use my laptop to ssh the NUC when collecting data. Both my laptop and the NUC connect to a 4G router via `wifi`. Please have a look at the picture.
[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzefB.png).

**Without connecting the LiDAR ethernet cable to the NUC**, I can ssh from my laptop to the NUC and everything works fine.

However, if I connect the ethernet cable to the NUC to get the LiDAR data, I can't ssh the NUC anymore.

From my laptop:

```
ifconfig
wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:f3:9a:fe:bc:fd  
          inet addr:192.168.1.57  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:2121:2cf:cb55:ec0:c6f0:be03:abe0/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::65d3:f133:761d:874f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39366 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28429 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26621126 (26.6 MB)  TX bytes:6555066 (6.5 MB)
```

```
ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0  scope link  metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.57  metric 600
```

From the NUC,

```
ifconfig
wlp58s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:63:3f:5c:55:5d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.51  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:2121:284:9781:d43c:1456:9f1c:fa41/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:2121:284:9781:f9ac:1884:54fe:af15/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::310b:eb87:967e:cc63/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:394 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:65555 (65.5 KB)  TX bytes:52734 (52.7 KB)
```

```
ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp58s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp58s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp58s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.51  metric 600
```

**On the NUC, after connecting the LiDAR ethernet cable**, I can not `ping` local IPs (gateway`192.168.1.1` or my laptop), but I can ping `8.8.8.8`.

My guess is that I have to change some settings of `dnsmasq` but I have no idea what to change.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit 1** The [suggested solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639100/how-to-get-connection-to-both-wifi-as-well-as-lan-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts) doesn't work for me. On the NUC I can use *both* wifi and LAN without problem. I *can not* use my laptop, which is connected to the same Wifi network, to SSH the NUC (the NUC is connected to the LiDAR via an ethernet cable). Note that, ***without*** plugging in the LiDAR's ethernet cable, I can SSH the NUC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get connection to both wifi as well as LAN in ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639100/how-to-get-connection-to-both-wifi-as-well-as-lan-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks for pointing out. I have tried that setup but it did not solve the problem. As soon as I manually enable the connection to the ethernet interface, I can't ping anything anymore.